# ThreadPoolExecutor on long running process

Tags: python, concurrency

I want to use ThreadPoolExecutor on a webapp (django),

All examples that I saw are using the thread pool like that:

`with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=1) as executor:
    code`

I tried to store the thread pool as a class member of a class and to use `map` fucntion

but I got memory leak, the only way I could use it is by the `with` notation

so I have 2 questions:

1. Each time I run `with ThreadPoolExecutor` does it creates threads again and then release them, in other word is this operation is expensive?
2. If I avoid using `with` how can I release the memory of the threads

thanks

Comment: you're using the `concurrent.futures` library, is that correct?

Comment: The `with` automatically cleans up the executor and destroys its threads as soon as the `with` statement ends. If you want to keep the executor alive as a class member, you do not want a `with`. Instead, you want to keep it alive as long as you want it alive, and call `close` (and `del` the attribute) whenever you’re finally done with it.

Comment: Also, if you’re still using an object, the fact that its memory is still alive is not a memory leak. If you create a list of a million items and keep it around for later, you don’t get the memory for those million items back until you finish using the list and release it. It’s the same thing here

Comment: As a side note, why are you setting `max_workers` to 1? That means you create a single thread, hand that thread all of your work, and then block until it finishes. This has the same effect as just calling the work in your main thread, but with extra complexity and overhead. Normally you use a pool because you want to do a bunch of the tasks concurrently—e.g., with 12 workers fetching data off a server, you may be able to finish things 6-12 times as fast as just doing it in your main thread, but with 1 worker it’ll be a bit slower instead of a lot faster.

Comment: I just copied an example from the documentation I am using with 30 threads

Answer (score 0):

Normally, web applications are stateless. That means every object you create should live in a request and die at the end of the request. That includes your `ThreadPoolExecutor`. Having an executor at the application level may work, but it will be embedded into your web application instead of running as a separate group of processes.

So if you want to take the workers down or restart them, your web app will have to restart as well.

And there will be stability concerns, since there is no main process watching over child processes detecting which one has gotten stale, so requires a lot of code to get multiprocessing right.

Alternatively, If you want a persistent group of processes to listen to a job queue and run your tasks, [there](https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/) [are](https://django-q.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) [several](https://github.com/dabapps/django-db-queue) [projects](https://docs.dask.org/en/stable/_modules/distributed/queues.html) that do that for you. All you need to do is to set up a server that takes care of queueing and locking such as redis or rabbitmq, then point your project at that server and start the workers. [Some](https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/) [projects](https://github.com/dabapps/django-db-queue) even let you use the database as a job queue backend.